# Can't open multiple connections with ssh.net in IIS environment

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssh.net

I'm using the ssh.net library to communicate with another server as part of a ASP.NET application.

I noticed using TCPView there is ever only one connection via SSH to the outgoing server at a time, the IIS server doesn't open one SSH connection per web request like I would expect. This is causing huge performance issues as only one request can be handled at a time - and must complete before a new one starts. Meanwhile, the other requests wait.

How can I allow the ssh.net library or the IIS server to open as many connections as required?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?